# Why do the accumulators from the C++ boost library have a function-like interface?

Tags: c++, boost, interface, boost-accumulators

In the boost library, we use accumulators like this:

```cpp
acc(1); // push things into acc
cout << max( acc ) << endl; // get its result
```

Why can't we define its interface like this:

```cpp
acc.push(1);
cout << acc.max() << endl;
```

So why do the accumulators from the boost library have a function-like interface? What is the advantage of it?

Answer (score 1):

Here are two reasons:

1. You can pass them to algorithms, such as `for_each`:

   ```
   acc = std::for_each(range.begin(), range.end(), acc);
   ```
2. This gives all accumulators a uniform interface. This is helpful to combine them eg. with `accumulator_set`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my guess

The reason that operator `()` is used for pushing instead of `push()` is because `acc(value)` reads *"accumulate another value"* which sounds more natural than `acc.push(value)` which is *"push a value to the accumulator"*

Besides the accumulator can receive *optional features* like *covariate* or *weight* and that way probably the result looks and sounds better than `acc.push(value, feature)`. Some examples from [the documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/doc/html/accumulators/user_s_guide.html):

```
acc( 1.2, covariate1 =  12 );
acc( 2.3, covariate1 = -23 );
acc( 3.4, covariate1 =  34 );
acc( 4.5, covariate1 = -45 );

acc(1, weight = 2); //   1 * 2
acc(2, weight = 4); //   2 * 4
acc(3, weight = 6); // + 3 * 6

acc(1, weight = 2, covariate1 = 3);
acc(0, weight = 4, covariate1 = 4);
acc(2, weight = 9, covariate1 = 8);
```

And then `max(acc)` is used instead of `acc.max()` because it allows **extensibility** while still **maintaining consistency**. By writing a new function that receives an accumulator you'll be able to do other things to the accumulated list

```
std::cout << "Mean:   " << mean(acc) << std::endl;
std::cout << "Moment: " << accumulators::moment<2>(acc) << std::endl;
```

If a member method was used then there'll only be a limited number of default operations like `acc.mean()`, `acc.max()`, the remaining things must be used like a function such as `product(acc)`, `rolling_moment<2>(acc)`, `kurtosis(acc)`, `skewness(acc)`... which breaks consistency